# Buffer all polygon feature classes inside geodatabase using ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, arcgis-10.4, dissolve

I have a geodatabase which contain a hundred of separated polygon feature classes. I want to create a same value buffer of all feature classes in same time. Each buffer must have a "dissolve"  option. Note that all FCs inside geodatabase have one same column needed for dissolve. I have tried to use ArcGIS buffer tool for each FC but that is very slow. Now I need something faster. Also I have tried to merge all of these files and create buffer with dissolve but in that case some small polygons will be lost.

Comment: Add class name to all f.classes (search this forum) , merge all and concatenate 2 fields, to be used for buffer with dissolve.

Comment: @FelixIP Ineresting solution but are you sure that some small polygons smaller than buffer size will not be lost in this case?  Also if you are sure that works add this as answer with more details.

Comment: @SonofaBeach I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an alternative to manually buffering each fc code below will work. Each output fc will be named after the input +'_buffered'

```py
import arcpy,os
ingdb = r'C:\Default.gdb' #Change
outgdb = r'C:\Default.gdb' #Change
dissolvefield = 'Somefield' #Change
buffdist = '100 Meters' #Change

arcpy.env.workspace = ingdb
polyfcs = [os.path.join(ingdb,fc) for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='Polygon')]
arcpy.env.workspace = outgdb
for poly in polyfcs:
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features=poly, out_feature_class=os.path.basename(poly)+'_buffered', 
                         buffer_distance_or_field=buffdist, 
                         dissolve_option='ALL', 
                         dissolve_field=dissolvefield)
```